# Increase size of TableView header

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

Using storyboard, I made this `UITableViewController`:

[image]

Ok, when I start search, in `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:` I will hide navigation bar and show the scope bar:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self.mySearchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];
    [self.mySearchBar sizeToFit];
    [self.mySearchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

But the first cell of table is hidden behind the scope bar. I think I need increase the table header, but how I do this? Or have some other way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, looking a little further I found a solution that seems most correct, which is using `UISearchDisplayController`. Here is the tutorial I followed: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html

Using this way, he hides the navigation bar and displays the scope without the need for additional codes and without the problem of the first cell being hidden.

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewDelegate has a method that does this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //return height as a float here
}
```

Implement that in your delegate with the appropriate height.

Alternatively, if the bar is hiding the top of the cell, you may need to move the table view down on the screen by changing its frame like so:

```
CGRect newFrame = tableView.frame;
newFrame.origin.y += 45; //or whatever number of pixels you want to move it down by
tableView.frame = newFrame;
```